# Is the "scores" tag necessary?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

I just saw the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11617172/how-to-access-highscores-from-flash-games and realized it had the [scores](/questions/tagged/scores) tag associated with it.  This tag has no wiki entry, and a large number of recent questions with this tag have 0 or negative net votes:

- [What is the easiest way to keep track of scores?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235444/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-keep-track-of-scores) (-3)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11389632/when-i-move-to-next-level-it-affects-on-score-and-hints-but-when-moving-level-ba (-4)
- [how to add score to higher or lower game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11081951/how-to-add-score-to-higher-or-lower-game) (0)
- [How to create a live scorer app for Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10361541/how-to-create-a-live-scorer-app-for-android) (-1)

Does this tag really add anything to these questions, and is it necessary?

Comment: Wow, there's a `burninate-request` tag?  That's fantastic

Comment: Call Trogdor!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agreed, it is now burninated.

[image: tag burninated]